# get a list of items inside a folder in document library

Tags: workflow, custom-actions, splistitemcollection

I built the following code so far:

```
        SPWeb web = __Context.Web;
        Guid listGuid = new Guid(__Context.ListId);
        SPList myList = web.Lists[listGuid];
        SPListItem myItem = myList.GetItemById(__Context.ItemId);

        if (myItem.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            // This item is a folder, need to check if it has an .doc file inside
            ???
        }
```

How do I obtain the collection of items inside myItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SPFolder folder = myItem.File.ParentFolder;
SPFileCollection items = folder.Files;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use SPQuery and set its ViewAttribute property.
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";